# Yii2 Gii Table Prefix

Tags: yii2, gii

I allways setup table prefix - for this post lets say my prefix is `abc_`.
So in `common\config\main-local.php`. I have:

```
'components' => [
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pwd',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'abc_',
],
...
```

I have worked on Yii1 and used gii to generate models.
In this version it generated files like: `table.php`.

Now I work with Yii2 and learn the differences:
`gii` generate files like `abc_table.php`. Yes - I checked "Use Table Prefix".

This is not ok because prefix should be transparent.
Could please anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may change the model class name `AbcTest` to `Test`. For future model generations, check the `Use Table Prefix` field in the `Gii` tool. `Gii` generate correct model like this:

```
class Test extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%test}}';
    }
    ...
}
```

In `tableName` method, it returns `'{{%test}}'` if you check `Use Table Prefix` in the `Gii` tool. If you do not check the `Use Table Prefix`, this method return `'abc_test'` and generated model class will be named as AbcTest.

Comment: Thanks - I should have seen this - I always referred to suggested values