# Yii2 migrations. Percentage sign and brackets in table name

Tags: yii2

I browsed the yii2-oauth2-server code on github and encountered interesting syntax in the [migration file](https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server/blob/master/migrations/m140501_075311_add_oauth2_server.php#L42). The code in question looks like this:

```
    $this->createTable('{{%oauth_clients}}', [
        ...
    ], $tableOptions);
```

Can someone explain the `{{%oauth_clients}}` part? What does it mean when the table name is enclosed in `{{%..}}`? The [official documentation on migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html) says nothing about it and all examples have the "raw" table names like this:

```
    $this->createTable('post_tag', [
        ...
    ]);
```

I checked my database and the table was created as if there were no brackets, its name is simply `oauth_clients`.

Comment: I might be wrong but I suspect it's to do with table prefixes eg: app_oauth_clients

Comment: @eskimo it seems you are right, I've found [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998385/yii2-gii-table-prefix) about Gii and the same syntax was used in the ActiveRecord class, seems logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is used for table prefix

From yii2 [documentation on Db connection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#$tablePrefix-detail):

> If a table name is given as `{{%TableName}}`, then the percentage
>   character `%` will be replaced with this property value. For example,
>   `{{%post}}` becomes `{{tbl_post}}`.

Comment: So what about the braces? The % is only one of the strange things about it, and the documentation is completely silent about the `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: @ThrowAwayAccount  the sample is obtained  form the yii2 DB connection doc  ..https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#$tablePrefix-detail

Comment: Curly brakets must be there to enable proper quoting of table names to avoid naming conflict e.g. with reserved keywords. This is because database systems support different quotes, e.g. mySQL/MariaDB uses backticks `\`table\`` or MSSQL square brackets `[table]` etc.