# Yii2 migrate/create with {{%table}} option

Tags: php, yii2, database-migration

Is it possible to create a migration using the `yii migrate/create` command in Yii2, which can create a table with table prefix?

For example:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('{{%settings}}', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'keyname' => $this->string()->unique(),
        'description' => $this->text(),
        'value' => $this->string(),
        'type' => $this->string()
    ]);
}
```

I want to get result like above example, but `yii migrate/create` command creates without {{%...}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
yii migrate/create name --useTablePrefix=1
```

Comment: May I know what's the purpose of `{{%...}}`? thankyou

Comment: @Blackjack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698129/yii2-migrations-percentage-sign-and-brackets-in-table-name

Comment: @Bizley thanks for the knowledge :) I've any issue about prefix, can you take a look my SO?